# Coldfusion8 - Decompressing GZ files using Coldfusion 8

Tags: coldfusion, gzip

On a daily basis I am download a GZ file that I will then need to decompress and import the contents into my database table.

I found CFX_Gzip.dll from Adobe Coldfusion Exchange.  Anyone know where i put the DLL file?
It might go in the CF8/lib/ folder, but i'm not sure.

I'm using Coldfusion8.  If there is another gzip decompressor that i should use, i'd be delighted if there is one that is more recent. This one is old and the website from the person that wrote it is gone now. No documentation with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit of java to process gzip files
http://www.cflib.org/udf/gzip

Comment: @Sergii - How is that possible? ;)

Comment: @Sergii - Haha. You are doing well then. My brain enters shutdown mode much earlier ;)

Answer (score 6):

No need of a dll with CF8, use existing java library. Have a look at [CFLib](http://CFLib.org) or try the following code:

```
<cfscript>
try{
    /* Set inoutput */
    gzFileName = "myFile.gz";
    outputFile = "mygzFiles";

    /* Initialize gzip */
    var outStream = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileOutputStream");
    var inStream = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream");
    var inGzipStream = CreateObject("java","java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream");

    outStream.init(outputFile);
    inStream.init(arguments.gzipFilePath);

    inGzipStream.init(instance.ioInput);

    while(l GTE 0){
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, l);
        l = inGzipStream.read(buffer);
    }

    /* Close the GZip file */
    inGzipStream.close();
    inStream.close();
    outStream.ioOutput.close();

} catch(Any){}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: It is best not swallow errors though. On error, the streams should be closed (to ensure nothing is left in a locked state) and the error reported.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Seems that we were all "in-sync" to answer that question :-)

Comment: Yep. With everyone suggesting the same thing, probably means it is the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the most elegant solution, but seems to work for my simple test cases:

```
<cfscript>

    inputFile = "/tmp/test.txt.gz";
    outputFile = "/tmp/test.txt";

    ioInput = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream");
    gzInput = CreateObject("java","java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream");
    ioOutput = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileOutputStream");

    ioInput.init(inputFile);
    gzInput.init(ioInput);
    ioOutput.init(outputFile);

    line = 0;
    buffer = RepeatString(" ", 1024).getBytes();

    while (line GTE 0) {
        ioOutput.write(buffer, 0, line);
        line = gzInput.read(buffer);
    }

    gzInput.close();
    ioInput.close();
    ioOutput.close();

</cfscript>
```

Comment: thank you for the replies. I ended up using a CFX called CFX_GZIP.